# Python 3.8 - Execute Python 3.8 in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.8

Python 3.8 installed on Windows 10 in C:\Python directory. C:\Python and C:\Python\Scripts added to both system and user environmental variables (path). (See attached image.)[image]

But, Python won't run from a command line. When I type python, the Microsoft Store pops up asking to install Python 3.7.

I have to be in the C:\Python directory and I have to type python.exe for it to run.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your launched that command prompt before editing the `PATH` environment variable, as the Python install directory isn't in the `path` output. The new environment settings are only applied to fresh prompts, not existing ones.

But really, don't bother with that anyway. Just use [the `py.exe` Windows launcher](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) which is automatically placed in your Windows directory (e.g. `C:\Windows`) which is *already* in your `PATH`. To launch with the latest installed Python 3, just run:

```
py -3
```

for the latest Python 2:

```
py -2
```

If you had the installer associate the launcher with the `.py` extension, you can put shebang lines in your scripts and they'll "Just Work". For GUI apps, `pyw.exe` and the `.pyw` extension serve the same purpose.

Comment: Thanks for that. py worked great! And, it launched 3.8, as expected.

Comment: ...You mentioned the launcher. I am having a problem with that as well. I don't recall specifically associating the launcher with .py files. And, #! doesn't work - "not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
I have to be in the python directory and type py.exe script.py or python.exe script.py.

Comment: Is there a way to go back and have the launcher associated?

Comment: @T2true: `py.exe` should work from anywhere, not just the Python directory, even if it wasn't associated with `.py` files. The association just allows you to double-click them (or run them as executables from the command line) without needing to mention `py`/`python` at all. You can always just reinstall Python and make sure the right boxes are checked.